# zsh: count lines in a command substitution

Tags: zsh

I want to count the number of lines generated by a command substitution `$(blah)` using zsh instead of piping through `wc -l`.  I know how to turn the command substitution lines into an array, like this:

```
blah_output=(${(f)"$(blah)"})
```

…and counting the number of items in an array is just this:

```
${#blah_output}
```

My question is: how can I do that in one expression, without the intermediate variable?  After some fiddling, I came up with this:

```
${#${(f)"$(blah)"}}
```

…which works unless `blah` returns only one line, at which point it returns the number of characters in that line, and I don't understand why or how to fix it.  What's the real answer?  Is there one?

Sub-questions:

1. When creating the initial array, I don't understand why the outer parentheses are necessary; I expected that splitting would imply an array value.
2. I don't understand why the quotes around `$(blah)` are necessary; if I don't include them, I get one element with the line break transformed into a space.  Something about an implicit word split and then join?